# Printing problems with IE8

Tags: windows-xp

I have had IE 8 for a while and all has been OK.  I'm running XP SP3 on a Lenovo T500 and Office 2007 Pro.  Suddenly I notice all downloded pages only print a small area in the top left of the page.  We have changed no printers or anything.  If you go to Page Setup in IE8 it defaults to 'Letter' and the margins are Left 19.05, Right 119.89, Top 19.05 and Bottom 147.07, so no wonder it only prints a small area.  However you try, it won't change from those settings.  You can click A4 and make the settings 19.05 for all margins which is standard, but as soon as you leave the screen, it just reverts back to the messed up settings.  I have uninstalled IE8 and Reinstalled, but all is still the same.  Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the default printing settings.

Go to the Control Panel, and then the Printers and Faxes section.  Right-click your printer, and click on the properties, to set the default paper/margin settings.

Comment: Thanks!  All printers are set to A4 and print fine as long as it's not something downloaded.  As soon as it comes through IE, it picks up the messed up page settings from there, which I cannot change, no matter what I try!